# Communication between WIFI Access Points

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm planning on building a wifi network for the purposes of research into WIFI Location tracking.

The network itself is not going to be carrying any data of note, it will purely be used by my host device for measuring RSSI from the access points (in order to calculate distance related signal attenuation).

Im confident i can easily enough build a network to accommodate most of needs EXCEPT I need to also be able to measure RSSI BETWEEN access points (IE, I need access point A to be able to read RSSI from point B and vice versa) in order to create a realtime interference map.

My question is:

Are there any commercially available AP'S that can communicate with other AP's? If so what specific specification should i be looking for to enable me to know that a particular AP has this capability?

**EDIT**
Having just read through other posts on this site I can see how this might be construed as a 'shopping list' question. I am not after answers such as 'netgear blah xyz does this'. I wish to know IF they are commercially available and what I should be looking for (do access points of this nature have a certain name etc)

Comment: Yes, there are devices that can communicate with a wireless AP, sadly most of those, simply extend that AP's signal.  You might have to come up with a work-around perhaps use Window's 7 ability to become an AP.

Comment: @Ramhound do you think I could obtain this functionality if I used wireless routers in a adhoc network instead of using AP's?